# TSQL Fuzzy Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have rows with descriptions as pasted below:

```
DAS0_CIP.TRA_HVAC01_073.TRA_HVAC_BCK.TRA_HVAC_CLX.Program:AHU_5.
DAS0_CIP.TRA_HVAC01_072.TRA_HVAC_BCK.TRA_HVAC_CLX.Program:AHU_5.
```

These are VERY similar but not quite the same.  Unfortunately, Soundex won't work to group them and I don't think I can use a two record compare function because I have a table with 7 million records that I need to group by the description.  I want similar descriptions to group together.  Is there a way to score or rank the similarity of rows?  How would I group these together in a better manner?

Right now, I group by the left([description],50) or something like that to get a rough grouping, but it's not really that accurate.  I'm figuring there must be a better way.

Extended data example:

```
[GREDS2UA1381TFT][MR_Data_2]MRSaveData Script:  Sproc failed to Update
!ERR Invalid hpItemArray in AlmLinkedList::AddItemAtEnd
!ERR Invalid hpItemArray in AlmLinkedList::GetItemPtrAt
!ERR Semaphore wait failed in CBThrd_CallbackThreadMain [hCBThreadSemaphore=000001AC]
!WNAL_Register(AlarmPriority10b) - failed(501)
!WNALderegister AlarmMgr not running
!WNAPalarm AlarmMgr not running
.Initialize(Label Details ToteStacker Manual): EntID or AreaName is bad: EntID= 0| AreaName= 
.RefreshGrid(Reprint): No production labels found with filters
.RefreshMaterialsGrid [PRODUCE]:  - Fact.Common.XMLReadBuilder
{1a} MES_CheeseMakeVatL1_AppEngine: StopHostedObjects() - m_AccessManagerProvider->UnregisterAutomationObjectNoUpdate( objectId = 16 ) failed, hr = 0x8000FFFF
{1a} MES_CheeseMakeVatL1_AppEngine: StopHostedObjects() - m_AccessManagerProvider->UnregisterAutomationObjectNoUpdate( objectId = 3 ) failed, hr = 0x80070057
[GRE_CM_REC_OS3][MR_Data_2]MRSaveData Script:  objResult Not Successful Proxy failed to connect to Middleware Server service endpoint. This can happen if your Middleware Server is not available or if the service endpoint portqueue is not accessible. The endpoint is [net.tcp:GRECMESDB1:8099FactMES.Server.HostEventBrokerSvc].
{1a} MES_StarterL1_AppEngine: StopHostedObjects() - m_AccessManagerProvider->UnregisterAutomationObjectNoUpdate( objectId = 8 ) failed, hr = 0x80070057
{1a} MES_StarterL1_AppEngine: StopHostedObjects() - m_AccessManagerProvider->UnregisterAutomationObjectNoUpdate( objectId = 9 ) failed, hr = 0x8000FFFF
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2542, 20160313 03:31:23.009, 20160313 03:31:23.008) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2560, 20160313 03:22:55.884, 20160313 03:22:55.883) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2560, 20160313 03:22:55.884, 20160313 03:22:55.883) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 3782]
[GREDS2UA1381TFT][MR_Data_2]MRSaveData Script:  Unable to get session instance
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:27:09.509, 20160313 03:27:09.508) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 3651]
{1a} MES_StarterL1_AppEngine: StopHostedObjects() - m_AccessManagerProvider->UnregisterAutomationObjectNoUpdate( objectId = 10 ) failed, hr = 0x80070057
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:35:36.037, 20160313 03:35:36.036) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 2380]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:39:50.371, 20160313 03:39:50.371) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
{1a} MES_StarterL1_AppEngine: StopHostedObjects() - m_AccessManagerProvider->UnregisterAutomationObjectNoUpdate( objectId = 3 ) failed, hr = 0x80070057
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:52:29.264, 20160313 03:52:29.264) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 3598]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:56:41.972, 20160313 03:56:41.971) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 776]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2588, 20160313 03:44:03.194, 20160313 03:44:03.194) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
{1a} MES_SweetWheyL1_AppEngine: StopHostedObjects() - m_AccessManagerProvider->UnregisterAutomationObjectNoUpdate( objectId = 7 ) failed, hr = 0x8000FFFF
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2588, 20160313 03:44:03.194, 20160313 03:44:03.194) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 3199]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:27:07.759, 20160313 03:27:07.758) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2542, 20160313 03:31:23.009, 20160313 03:31:23.008) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 3472]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:27:09.509, 20160313 03:27:09.508) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:35:36.037, 20160313 03:35:36.036) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:27:07.759, 20160313 03:27:07.758) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 332]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:31:20.290, 20160313 03:31:20.290) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:35:35.019, 20160313 03:35:35.018) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:35:35.019, 20160313 03:35:35.018) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 233]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:39:50.959, 20160313 03:39:50.959) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 253]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:44:04.936, 20160313 03:44:04.936) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:44:04.936, 20160313 03:44:04.936) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 289]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:52:30.967, 20160313 03:52:30.967) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:39:50.371, 20160313 03:39:50.371) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 2725]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:52:30.967, 20160313 03:52:30.967) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 326]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:48:17.312, 20160313 03:48:17.312) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:48:17.312, 20160313 03:48:17.312) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 3683]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:52:29.264, 20160313 03:52:29.264) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A2C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2579, 20160313 03:56:41.972, 20160313 03:56:41.971) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:22:55.228, 20160313 03:22:55.227) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:22:55.228, 20160313 03:22:55.227) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 331]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:31:20.290, 20160313 03:31:20.290) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 325]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:39:50.959, 20160313 03:39:50.959) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:48:18.899, 20160313 03:48:18.899) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:48:18.899, 20160313 03:48:18.899) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 316]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:56:44.589, 20160313 03:56:44.588) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2100, 20160313 03:35:40.381, 20160313 03:35:40.380) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2101, 20160313 03:22:59.993, 20160313 03:22:59.993) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2101, 20160313 03:22:59.993, 20160313 03:22:59.993) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1097]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:27:13.618, 20160313 03:27:13.618) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:27:13.618, 20160313 03:27:13.618) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1092]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:31:27.118, 20160313 03:31:27.118) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 992]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:39:53.131, 20160313 03:39:53.131) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:39:53.131, 20160313 03:39:53.131) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 798]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:44:07.930, 20160313 03:44:07.930) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1008]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:48:21.578, 20160313 03:48:21.577) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:22:55.884, 20160313 03:22:55.883) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 419]
0:A58 Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2233, 20160313 03:56:44.589, 20160313 03:56:44.588) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 66]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:31:23.009, 20160313 03:31:23.008) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2100, 20160313 03:35:40.381, 20160313 03:35:40.380) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 725]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:35:37.598, 20160313 03:35:37.597) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:31:27.118, 20160313 03:31:27.118) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:44:07.930, 20160313 03:44:07.930) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:48:21.578, 20160313 03:48:21.577) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1143]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:52:37.035, 20160313 03:52:37.034) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:52:37.035, 20160313 03:52:37.034) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1161]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:39:53.494, 20160313 03:39:53.493) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 306]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:56:50.535, 20160313 03:56:50.535) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A5C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2103, 20160313 03:56:50.535, 20160313 03:56:50.535) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 183]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:44:05.698, 20160313 03:44:05.698) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 355]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:22:55.884, 20160313 03:22:55.883) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:48:18.453, 20160313 03:48:18.452) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:27:09.509, 20160313 03:27:09.508) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:48:18.453, 20160313 03:48:18.452) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 390]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:27:09.509, 20160313 03:27:09.508) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 416]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:31:23.009, 20160313 03:31:23.008) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 393]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:56:48.585, 20160313 03:56:48.584) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 71]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:35:37.598, 20160313 03:35:37.597) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 291]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:39:53.494, 20160313 03:39:53.493) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:44:05.698, 20160313 03:44:05.698) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2288, 20160313 03:42:55.241, 20160313 03:42:55.240) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:52:32.720, 20160313 03:52:32.719) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2288, 20160313 03:42:55.241, 20160313 03:42:55.240) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 639]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2294, 20160313 03:38:43.218, 20160313 03:38:43.218) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 442]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:52:32.720, 20160313 03:52:32.719) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 401]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2249, 20160313 03:56:48.585, 20160313 03:56:48.584) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2338, 20160313 03:55:38.184, 20160313 03:55:38.184) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2294, 20160313 03:38:43.218, 20160313 03:38:43.218) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2336, 20160313 03:51:24.094, 20160313 03:51:24.094) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2344, 20160313 03:34:28.353, 20160313 03:34:28.352) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 455]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2344, 20160313 03:59:50.704, 20160313 03:59:50.703) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2336, 20160313 03:51:24.094, 20160313 03:51:24.094) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 841]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2338, 20160313 03:55:38.184, 20160313 03:55:38.184) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 670]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2343, 20160313 03:47:09.092, 20160313 03:47:09.091) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 1]
0:A6C Attempt to store values in the future; timestamps were overwritten with current time (2343, 20160313 03:47:09.092, 20160313 03:47:09.091) [aahMDASSF.cpp; 3315; 658]
A write to InTouch was skipped with a value of  because the data quality was bad or initializing.
A write to InTouch was skipped with a value of CM__Ctrl because the data quality was bad or initializing.
A write to InTouch was skipped with a value of false because the data quality was bad or initializing.
```

Comment: If it's only numbers that differ, maybe you could replace numbers with an empty string to do the comparison on that. But also like @TT. said, when are they similar enough to be grouped together?

Comment: Please explain your expected result.

Comment: One solution is Levenshtein distance, another is n-gram count.  Both would be rather expensive on 7 million rows.

Comment: Your strings look like they're generated systematically. If you can find the pattern, you can eliminate it (by replacing the appropriate variable portions) and then join on the general template. This would certainly beat matching them "kinda sorta" (by whatever fuzzy matching algorithm), because it presumably matters quite a bit whether the two rows really belong together in a systematic data set.

Comment: Are there always 5 parts divided by a `.`? Is *similarity* equal with *How many parts are the same?*

Comment: Your *extended data* is really awful... :-( There will - for sure! - be no easy way to compare 7m rows each with each... Where is this data generated?I'd start to try to identify large common parts like *Attempt to store values in the future* or *!ERR Invalid hpItemArray in AlmLinkedList::* and replace them with a short string of two characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9 gives 3844 different codes, this should suffice). Try to throw away what you don't need and write a cleaned string into a new column (or maybe several columns)...

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be this: It will test, how many parts are identical... You might continue with this idea into each part splitting this by `_`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestSimilarity(@s1 VARCHAR(100),@s2 VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x1 XML=CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@s1,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML);
    DECLARE @x2 XML=CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@s2,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML);

    DECLARE @retVal INT=0;
    IF @x1.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)')= @x2.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)') SET @retVal=@retVal+1;
    IF @x1.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')= @x2.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)') SET @retVal=@retVal+1;
    IF @x1.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')= @x2.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)') SET @retVal=@retVal+1;
    IF @x1.value('/x[4]','varchar(100)')= @x2.value('/x[4]','varchar(100)') SET @retVal=@retVal+1;
    IF @x1.value('/x[5]','varchar(100)')= @x2.value('/x[5]','varchar(100)') SET @retVal=@retVal+1;

    RETURN @retVal;
END;
GO

SELECT dbo.TestSimilarity('DAS0_CIP.TRA_HVAC01_073.TRA_HVAC_BCK.TRA_HVAC_CLX.Program:AHU_5.','DAS0_CIP.TRA_HVAC01_072.TRA_HVAC_BCK.TRA_HVAC_CLX.Program:AHU_5.');
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestSimilarity;
```

The result would be 4...

Comment: How would you use this to group 7 million rows? Evaluating the function for every pair is going to take a while. And when I say "a while"...

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are right - of course... The OP did not yet answer, if this approach (*similarity equals count of identical parts*) is correct. I'd probably add columns and split the string into these columns as a one-time-action (and maybe triggered for later changes). Then you could compare these columns "as ever"

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you for the response, however, like Jeroen said, a many-to-many join on 7 million plus rows would take a very long time.  I've come across this answer but I'm looking more for a Soundex-like solution that would take the description and break it down into an easily matchable string or dimensions.  I'm thinking something like the first dimension might be string length.  That would get me an idea that they are alike.  Then maybe another dimension that would be words or letters contained in the script.  Then possibly other dimensions and from those I would then create a match score.

Comment: @Derek, If you are the owner of the table, you might add columns to store the splitted parts... Regrettfully you did not define *similarity*. If my assumption is right and these are parts divided by dots my question was: How many different parts do exist? Could you replace them with something short? Could you try to create a compare string which is short and fitting for `soundex`?

Comment: @Derek It would help, if you'd provide more examples of your strings, also some being very different... Is there a common pattern?

Comment: @Shnugo I added a larger data sample to the question.  Hope that helps.